# I'm trying to deploy using env. but, it s not wokrin

Tags: contract-deployment, python

I'm having a really hard time.. I'm trying to set up the .emv so can work correctly think this is the problem.

**not missing..**

**dotenv: .env

wallets:

from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}**

Note:  copy both private keys one from infura project ID another one from metamask.
the problem seems to be the  .env file. I don't see de export reserved world and the variable name changing COLORS ...
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
export INFURA_PROJECT_ID=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

To:

```
export WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Example:

[image: Change to:]